# ASM snake game - issues resolving errors

Tags: assembly, x86

I am working on the ASM 1-player snake game. I am using GUI Turbo Assembler x64 to compile it.  This is the only error I got:
**Fatal Command line: Can't locate file: Snake_version_2.asm**
I googled the error and it says to name the file in less than 6-7 letters, so I renamed to snake.asm
Now these are all the errors I am getting now:

I'd like some help resolving these errors!

```
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12/3/2019 9:29:55 PM :     Assembling file - C:\Users\shriw\Downloads\Snake.asm
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     Turbo Assembler  Version 4.1  Copyright (c) 1988, 1996 Borland International
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     Assembling file:   Snake.asm
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     *Warning* Snake.asm(15) Reserved word used as symbol: STACK
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     **Error** Snake.asm(71) Illegal instruction
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     **Error** Snake.asm(100) Undefined symbol: SUB
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     *Warning* Snake.asm(100) Argument needs type override
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     **Error** Snake.asm(103) Undefined symbol: ADD
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     *Warning* Snake.asm(103) Argument needs type override
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     **Error** Snake.asm(106) Undefined symbol: SUB
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     **Error** Snake.asm(109) Undefined symbol: ADD
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     **Error** Snake.asm(136) Illegal instruction
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     **Error** Snake.asm(164) Illegal instruction
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     **Error** Snake.asm(165) Illegal instruction
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     Error messages:    8
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     Warning messages:  3
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     Passes:            1
12/3/2019 9:29:57 PM :     Remaining memory:  463k
```

Here is my code:

````
    snake dw 0101h,0102h,0103h,13 dup(0000h)
    graph db 9 dup('#'),0dh,0ah,'#*** #',0dh,0ah
    db 11 dup('#',7 dup(' '),'#',0dh,0ah)
    db 9 dup('#'),0dh,0ah,'$'
    win db 'Congrats! You Win!',0dh,0ah,'$'
    lose db 'What a pity! You lose!',0dh,0ah,'$'
    direction dw 0064h
    speed1 equ 1000h
    speed2 equ 0100h
Data ends

;stack segment definition
Stack segment stack
    dw 0ffh dup(?)
Stack ends

;additional segment definition
Extra segment
    snake_food dw 0b06h,0703h,0c01h,0204h,0606h,0a02h,0405h,0905h
    dw 0101h,0c04h,0502h,0207h,0c07h,0604h,0c02h,0304h
Extra ends

;code segment definition
Code segment
assume cs:Code,ds:Data,ss:Stack,es:Extra

;main program definition
start:
    mov ax,Data
    mov ds,ax
    mov ax,Stack
    mov ss,ax
    mov ax,Extra
    mov es,ax
    mov dx,offset graph
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    mov bx,0000h            ;snake tail position
    mov si,0002h            ;snake head position
    mov di,offset snake_food
    call food
    xor ax,ax

outloop:
    cmp al,0ffh
    jz gamewin
    cmp al,0f0h
    jz gamelose
    call nextstep
    jmp outloop

gamewin:
    mov dx,offset win
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    jmp gameover
gamelose:
    mov dx,offset lose
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
gameover:
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h

;Subroutine definition
;move forward one step
nextstep proc near
input:
    get_direction direction,speed1,speed2
    mov ax,direction
    cmp al,'a'
    jz m_l
    cmp al,'A'
    jz m_l
    cmp ah,4bh
    jz m_l
    cmp al,'d'
    jz m_r
    cmp al,'D'
    jz m_r
    cmp ah,4dh
    jz m_r
    cmp al,'w'
    jz m_u
    cmp al,'W'
    jz m_u
    cmp ah,48h
    jz m_u
    cmp al,'s'
    jz m_d
    cmp al,'S'
    jz m_d
    cmp ah,50h
    jz m_d
    jmp input

m_l:
    mov sub,0001h
    jmp ret_
m_r:
    mov add,0001h
    jmp ret_
m_u:
    mov sub,0100h
    jmp ret_
m_d:
    mov add,0100h
    jmp ret_
ret_: ret
nextstep endp

;judge next move
judge proc near ;00h:food,0fh:normal?f0h:block
push cx
mov ah,02h
int 10h
mov ah,08h
int 10h
mov ch,al
mov al,00h
cmp ch,'o'
jz outjudge
mov al,0fh
cmp ch,' '
jz outjudge
mov al,0f0h
outjudge:
pop cx
ret
judge endp

;food function
food proc near
Protect
inc si
and si,000fh
mov cx,bx

getfood:
    add di,0002h
    cmp di,20h
    jb go_on
    xor di,di
go_on:
    mov bx,cx ;make sure to start at the end of every inspection
lp:
    shl bx,1
    mov dx,es:[di]
    cmp dx,snake[bx]
    jz getfood
    shr bx,1
    inc bx
    and bx,000fh
    cmp bx,si
    jnz lp
    mov dx,es:[di]
    mov ah,02h
    int 10h
    mov al,'o'
    mov ah,0eh
    int 10h
Curser
Recover
ret
food endp
;end subroutine
Code ends
end start```
````

Comment: The error messages say exactly what is wrong. `STACK` is a reserved word; you cannot name your segment `STACK`. Line 71 is `get_direction direction,speed1,speed2` and there is no x86 instruction called `get_direction`. Line 100 is `mov sub,0001h`, but there is no variable named `sub`. And so on. If you don't understand a specific error, ask about that specific error (and indicate which line it is. Counting to 100 by hand is very tedious and error-prone.)

Comment: @Raymond I am sorry, I didn't realize that! We fixed the error of `mov sub, 0001h` by writing `move sub, 001h` and so on, now we get an illegal instruction error on those lines. All our 8 errors are now just illegal instruction errors. Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10WMhJOpSEMlyBRWND6r7fvVagi4a3dKw) to the highlighted codes that are having issues. TIA!

Comment: [edit] your question with the current version of your code and the actual error messages.  [mcve].  Leaving that in a comment is not helpful.  (BTW, I'd recommend *not* using `add` and `sub` as data symbol names!  Those are also instruction mnemonics in x86 so it looks really weird to have `add` as an operand for `mov`.)

Comment: This can't possibly be x64 code because the assembler is from '98 which was before x64 was released.

Comment: @mchychym The instruction is called `mov`, not `move`.  I'm not sure what you try to achieve here.

Comment: "Illegal instruction" means exactly that: The instruction you used was illegal. If you look in the processor manual, you'll see that there is no instruction called `get_direction` or `move`.